# Why does an explicitly-defaulted constructor give a 'function definition not found' warning in VS2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor

I'm working on a C++17 project compiled in VS2019. I have a class where I want to use an explicitly-defaulted constructor:

```
class UserCredentials
{
public:
    UserCredentials() = default;
};
```

With the code above, Visual Studio is giving me a green squigly underline warning:

> Function definition for 'UserCredentials' not found.

It seems like the warning is not taking account of the explicit default. If I put an empty constructor into my .cpp file, I get the opposite error: this function is already defined.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellisense uses a different compiler than the one used to compile code into an executable.

The Intellisense compiler has a problem with your code.  This may be a bug in Intellisense, or something about your code that it doesn't understand.   Your code itself is fine.